Error after downgrading from python 3.12.3 to 3.10.6
I was trying to play with stable diffusion and installed py3.12.3(latest) , after an issue arose I saw that someone recommended downgrading to py3.10.6.
I ran webui-user.bat (not important, this is more of a python issue than a stable diffusion issue) again and  after some debugging I reached this spot and I don't know what to do from here.
the error:
venv "C:\Users\myName\local\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
No Python at '"C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
I checked the PATH and its clear of any python3.12, I deleted any reference to python3.12 on my computer, with the uninstaller and just deleting folders after uninstalling.
I can't for the life of me find the folder that the error is referencing.
HELP

The error is telling you it can't find the file, so it's no wonder that you can't find it either.

See if you can find a reference in your environment variables or the registry.

You can try debugging this until the cows come home, but you're probably better off rebuilding the environment with the right version of Python. Anything you've run since first installing 3.12 may have made changes based on that version - getting rid of all references to it could be next to impossible. Downgrading Python is not really something that's supported in an environment, even upgrading Python is generally something you do by creating a new environment - you just bring the code.
